# Using a ternary expression in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-operator, ternary

In this component:

```
 const MovieComponent = (props) => {
  const { Poster, Price, Title, cinemaWorldPrice } = props.movie;

  return (
    <MovieContainer>
      <CoverImage src={Poster} alt="" />
      <MovieName>{Title}</MovieName>

      <InfoColumn>
        <MovieInfo>FilmWorld: ${Price}</MovieInfo>
        <MovieInfo>CinemaWorld: ${cinemaWorldPrice}</MovieInfo>
      </InfoColumn>
    </MovieContainer>
  );
};
```

I'm wanting to write a ternary expression that will change the font color of:

```
<MovieInfo>FilmWorld: ${Price}</MovieInfo>
        <MovieInfo>CinemaWorld: ${Price}</MovieInfo>
```

Something basically saying

```
if (Filmworld Price > CinemaWorld Price) { Filmworld Price = color: "green"}
```

and vice versa. Is this possible? And would the code be in the movie info section?
This is on React.

Comment: Based on the code I see, Price would always be equal. You might want to have separate values for it

Comment: How do you differentiate the FilmWorld price from the CinemaWorld price? I don't understand your code

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have edited the code if you would like to have another look?

Comment: @Aneesh I have updated the props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

- properly interpolate the prices into JSX (`${}` is only for template literals)
- surround the price texts in another element, like a span, so you can then conditionally color that span if needed

```
const MovieComponent = (props) => {
    const { Poster, Price, Title, cinemaWorldPrice } = props.movie;
    return (
        <MovieContainer>
            <CoverImage src={Poster} alt="" />
            <MovieName>{Title}</MovieName>
            <InfoColumn>
            <MovieInfo>
                    FilmWorld:
                    <span style={Price > cinemaWorldPrice ? { color: 'green' } : null}>{Price}</span>
                </MovieInfo>
                <MovieInfo>
                    CinemaWorld:
                    <span style={Price < cinemaWorldPrice ? { color: 'green' } : null}>{cinemaWorldPrice}</span>
                </MovieInfo>
            </InfoColumn>
        </MovieContainer>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly. 
A question for the future. If you wanted to add multiple stylings to the same span how would you separate them, ie adding a text-decoration or background-color?

Comment: Just add more properties to the object being put in the `style`. `{ color: 'green'; textDecoration: 'underline' }`